# Regex to match only 6-letter alphanumeric words in a string

Tags: java, c#, regex

I am trying to match the 6 character word that has a combination of ONLY alphanumeric.

Example String:

```
Bus Express Wash at bay no 083457 - Truckno AB96CD & Truck no 12367S & 12368S
```

I am currently trying regex `[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}`

However, it matches below Output:

```
xpress
083457
ruckno
AB96CD
12367S
12368S
```

But, what I need is only combination of alphanumeric. Something like below
Desired Output

```
AB96CD
12367S
12368S
```

Comment: You need to put word boundaries around your current pattern: `\b[A-Za-z0-9]{6}\b`.  BTW...your question is almost certainly a duplicate.

Comment: I tried that, it still matches the "083457" . It should only match combination of alphanumeric

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this regex with 2 lookahead conditions:

```bash
\b(?=[a-zA-Z]*\d)(?=\d*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]{6}\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJOTzV/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(?=[a-zA-Z]*\d)`: Lookahead to assert that we have at least one digit after 0 or more letters
- `(?=\d*[a-zA-Z])`: Lookahead to assert that we have at least one letter after 0 or more digits
- `[a-zA-Z\d]{6}`: Match 6 alphanumeric characters
- `\b`: Word boundary

Comment: Although this is correct, such regexes quickly become "write-only" (i.e. quite complicated and hard to debug later on). I would maybe just stick to Tim's suggestion of `\b[A-Za-z0-9]{6}\b` and then iterate the matches in code to figure out which ones are actual truck numbers.

Comment: That's just a personal choice. Matching and looping with 2 conditions will be very inefficient as compared to this suggestion. Lookaheads are used pretty much in every regex string validations and it is just a matter of getting used to it.

Comment: I disagree with CompuChip here.  I think that if you're reasonably comfortable with lookaheads, that regular expression makes perfect sense.  And if you're not comfortable with lookaheads, you can always refer to documentation.  There's not really a good reason not to use lookaheads and lookbehinds; and they're perfect for this particular problem.

Comment: You can replace 6-char limit by replacing `{6}` with the desired quantifier: one or more - `+`, zero or more - `*`, eight or more - `{8,}`, etc.